# Change Matplotlib line color only if palette is exhausted

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, color-palette

Using the `prop_cycle` parameter for colors and line styles in Matplotlib, I get a cycle through line styles every new curve. I want a change in line style *only* if the color palette is exhausted.

Let say my plot contains 10 curves and my color palette contains 8 colors, then I want the first 8 curves to be solid and the last two dashed. Is that possible?

Comment: Suggest reading about multiplication in the cycler docs: https://matplotlib.org/cycler/

Comment: @JodyKlymak thanks! That was exactly what I was searching for. Created a custom cycler while multiplying the line styles with colors like: `custom_cycler = cycler('linestyle', ['-', '--']) * cycler('color', [''green', 'blue', 'red'])`